# Keycloak login ith chrome extension

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-connect

I'm being started to implement keycloak SSO authentication on an existing homemade chrome extension in pure JS.
Keycloak server is well configured, i've checked that.
I'm able to import keycloak.json on background.js.
I'm able to init keycloak object :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8hODB.png)

But i'm a bit lost about login.
A click on login button should call keycloak.login function.
A simple `keycloak.login({redirectUri:`${url_extension_bckg}?action=login`});`
obviously doesn't work.
So i've found 1 example but running with angular :

```
async function login() {
  try {
    browser.identity.launchWebAuthFlow(
      {url: `https://AUTH_URL/auth/realms/realmName/protocol/openid-connect/auth?client_id=client&action=login`, interactive: true},
      (redirectURL) => {
        browser.extension.getBackgroundPage().console.log('result', redirectURL);
      }
    )
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
  
}
```

I've tried this but get "invalid parameter : redirect_uri".
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hecK2.png)
I can't achieve to build login URL.

Help would be appreciate.
I checked documentation but keycloak SSO check with chrome extension seems pretty rare...

Thanks in advance

Comment: Check that your redirect URI (`http://www.google.fr/`) is in the list of allowed redirect URIs for your client.

Comment: @sventorben I've just put that url for tests. Valid redirect urls in keycloak config is set to "*". And i've tested login process via calling keycloak.login function through a simple html/js  code and a locahost. Everything works fine. But inside my chrome extension, it doesn't work...

Comment: I've tried without
`(redirectURL) => {browser.extension.getBackgroundPage().console.log('result', redirectURL);}`
Without more success. Still "invalid parameter redirect_uri"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the way :)
Using control of storage token, which is always removed when i ask a log out on my extension.
I just check on popup if stored token is present. If not i call login function, which verify by SSO if still logged. If not, redirect to keycloak template login page.

Answer (score 1):

Taking a closer look at the second picture that you have provided. The URL shows that your parameter is called `redirectURI` instead of `redirect_uri`. Change that to `redirect_uri` and you should be fine.

Comment: Login url send back "redirect_uri not allowed" on console.
There's no more access to login page as shown on my second picture.

Answer (score 1):

@alainebdev Could you please provide more examples of your code? I faced the similar problem and cannot solve it yet.

Briefly what I am doing:

I use `keycloak.init()` (without options) in order to be able to use the `keycloak.createLoginUrl()` function, which creates the url that you described automatically. Next, I call the `launchWebAuthFlow` function in order to open a popup with an authorization interface, where we log in, get the url with authorization data, and return back to the application.

In the code, it looks like this:

```
keycloak.init()
  .then(auth => {
      const loginPageUrl = keycloak.createLoginUrl({redirectUri: 'https://<extension_id>.chromiumapp.org'})

      chrome.identity.launchWebAuthFlow({
          url: loginPageUrl,
          interactive: true
      }, authUrl => {
          console.log('authUrl: ', authUrl)
      }
  }
```

Everything is going smoothly up to this point. In this part of the code, I have an `authUrl` line with authorization data for Keyclak, I do not know how to make Keycloak read this data. None of its methods (`init` or `login`) have a corresponding property where I could pass it.

How do we make the Keycloak understand that we have received all the necessary data?

Comment: I didn't used keyckloak class object to use authentication. I just used launchWebAuthFlow because that function manage SSO too.
About redirect_uri, just use `const redirectURL = browser.identity.getRedirectURL();` which works fine.

Comment: const redirectURL = browser.identity.getRedirectURL();
const clientID = "**";
const scopes = "openid";
let loginURL = "https://***/auth/realms/lde-poplab/protocol/openid-connect/auth";
  loginURL += `?client_id=${clientID}`;
  loginURL += `&response_type=code`;
  loginURL += "&state = default";
  loginURL += `&redirect_uri=${encodeURIComponent(redirectURL)}`;
  loginURL += `&scope=${encodeURIComponent(scopes)}`;
  let url = {};
  try {
    url = await browser.identity.launchWebAuthFlow({
        interactive: true,
        url: loginURL,
      })
  } catch (err) {}

Comment: Above is function i used then i'm redirect to keycloak interactive login

Comment: i used response_type=code (added on url param function then i retrieve authorization code slicing url returned by launchWebAuthFlow

Comment: yes, it looks like the one I'm using, but the question is what to do next?
I get URL
`https://<extension_id>.chromiumapp.org/?session_state=b7884224-6b59-4e99-9824-801fca5f1696&code=38c04022-6a7c-4e3d-9235-f982fc588b499-4b7d98d -5f6c584ab41a` from `launchWebAuthFlow`, but how to further use this information, in particular the `code`, to get an access token?

Comment: build a request body : 
let details = {
    "redirect_uri" : redirectURL,
    "client_id": "poplab-front",
    "grant_type": "authorization_code",
    "code": code,
    "client_secret": CLIENT_SECRET,
    "scope": "openid",
  };
  
  let detailsBody = []
  for (let property in details) {
    let encodedKey = encodeURIComponent(property);
    let encodedValue = encodeURIComponent(details[property]);
    detailsBody.push(encodedKey + "=" + encodedValue);
  };
  detailsBody = detailsBody.join("&");
then

method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "urlencoded"
    }

Comment: And then fetch
let user = {};
  user = await fetch("https://***/auth/realms/lde-poplab/protocol/openid-connect/token", {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    },
    body: detailsBody
  })
and finally get token by this : 
.then(response => response.json())
  .then(response => {
    let userDetail = JSON.parse(atob(response.access_token.split('.')[1]));

Comment: @alainebdev, thanks a lot! it worked. My mistake was that I got too hung up on the keycloak-js library

Comment: Glad i could have helped you :)

Answer (score 0):

I've finally succeeded doing this :

```
async function login() {
  const redirectURL = browser.identity.getRedirectURL();
  console.log("redirectURL : ",redirectURL)
  const clientID = "*******";
  const scopes = "openid";
  let authURL = "https://URL_AUTH_SERVER/auth/realms/REALM_NAME/protocol/openid-connect/auth";
  authURL += `?client_id=${clientID}`;
  authURL += `&response_type=code`;
  authURL += "&state = default";
  authURL += `&redirect_uri=${encodeURIComponent(redirectURL)}`;
  authURL += `&scope=${encodeURIComponent(scopes)}`;

  return browser.identity.launchWebAuthFlow({
    interactive: true,
    url: authURL
  });
}
```

[keycloak Login Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8jZpN.png)
Then I'm redirected and come back on page I was when I clicked on extension button.
And I've checked cookies are rightly created (that needed 3 more lines on manifest.json). Now to confirm SSO feature OK, I just need to check if I can go on another app linked on keycloak and "enter" it as connected.
I'll do tomorrow but I'm pretty confident :D
Thank for help to all :)

Comment: In my extension, i have to check if user is still connected (while he could have logged off by another application).
I don't know how i can check that session is still opened or whatever that can tell me he is logged off.

Comment: I successed to check if login back needed using my login function with 1 parameter added as context of call.